# psql copy command hangs with large CSV data set

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm trying to load some large data sets from CSV into a Postgres 11 database (Windows) to do some testing. Fist problem I ran into was that with very large CSV I got this error: "ERROR: could not stat file "'D:/temp/data.csv'  Unknown error". So after searching, I found a workaround to load the data from a zip file. So I setup 7-zip and was able to load some data with a command like this:

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost -d MyTestDb -c "copy my_table(id,name) FROM PROGRAM 'C:/7z e -so d:/temp/data.zip' DELIMITER ',' CSV"
```

Using this method, I was able to load a bunch of files of varying sizes, one with 100 million records that was 700MB zipped. But then I have one more large file with 100 million records that's around 1GB zipped, that one for some reason is giving me grief. Basically, the psql process just keeps running and never stops. I can see based on data files growing that it generates data up to a certain point, but then at some point it stops growing. I'm seeing 6 files in a data folder named 17955, 17955.1, 17955.2, etc. up to 17955.5. The Date Modified date on those files continues to be updated, but they're not growing in size and my psql program just sits there. If I shut down the process, I lose all the data since I assume it rolls it back when the process does not run to completion.

I looked at the logs in the data/log folder, there doesn't seem to be anything meaningful there. I can't say I'm very used to Postgres, I've used SQL Server the most, so looking for tips on where to look, or what extra logging to turn on, or anything else that could help figure out why this process is stalling.

Comment: Do you have foreign key constraints on this table?

Comment: Yes, several. I did have several on the other table with 100 million records that succeeded though. But perhaps it's because the second 100 million record table has a foreign key to the first one?

Comment: It queues up the foreign keys and checks them at the end, so you won't see any write activity while it is doing that.

Comment: Would it make things better to remove the foreign keys, insert all the data, and re-add the foreign keys after?

Comment: @jjanes That did the trick, without the FKs things loaded fast and adding them back didn't take too long. If you write that up in an answer I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out thanks to @jjanes comment above (sadly he/she didn't add an answer). I was adding 100 million records to a table with a foreign key to another table with 100 million records. I removed the foreign key, added the records, and then re-added the foreign key, that did the trick. I guess checking the foreign keys is just too much with a bulk insert this size.